# Create Reset button for a counter

Tags: javascript, button, closures, counter, reset

I have this counter. It is a counter that uses Javascript Closure. Can you help me with a reset button?
If you can, to this type of "counter" code, not to another...

**HTML CODE**

```
<button type="button" onclick="geo()">Count!</button>
<p id="count">0</p>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
<script>
  var count= (function () {
  var nr = 0;
  return function () {nr+= 1; return nr;}
  })();

  function geo(){
      document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should explain what you're expecting to happen with your counter and what you're seeing happen instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure what you have right now is working.

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#add');
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('#reset');
const pCount = document.querySelector('#count')

let start = 0;


function add(){
  start++
  pCount.innerHTML = start
}

function reset(){
  start = 0;
  pCount.innerHTML = start
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', add)
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', reset)
```

```html
<button id="add"> Add </button>
<button  id="reset" > Reset </button>
<p id="count"></p>
```

Comment: Thank! Maybe I wasn't too clear. I don't want to use global variables. That's why the counter code is so designed to avoid global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the closure (seems very interesting...) but moving nr variable outside of your function and then call a reset on nr will reset the counter.

```js
var count = (function() {
  var nr = 0;
  return function(reset = false) {
    nr = reset ? 0 : nr + 1
    return nr;
  }
})();

function geo() {
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count();
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count(true);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="geo()">Count!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="reset()">Reset!</button>
<p id="count">0</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I wanted. I don't want to use the global variable. That is why it is the code above to avoid the global variable. Or you transformed the code with a global variable.

Comment: Hi, @Geo have a look at the updated solution. you can pass a variable to reset the counter to the function return from the closure.

Comment: Thanks! So I wanted. It's perfect!